# How long does it take to observe changes using drive.changes.list?

Tags: google-drive-api

We have unit tests we're writing in our application around drive.changes.list

1. User A modifies a file
2. User B tries to observe the changes using drive.changes.list()

Sometimes it takes a ~5 minutes for changes to show up, and at the other extreme changes show up in seconds. Sometimes they do not show up even after 5 minutes.

Is it a bug that changes in drive.changes.list don't show up even after 5 minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like our cache invalidation strategy. I'm not sure we can fix/improve the issue in the short term. Changes are not intended for meet realtime needs. But the good news is that, there is another feature in our scope that will address your needs.